# Why is the PDF rendered differently in Docusign comparing to all other renderers?

Tags: docusignapi

I sent a PDF to Docusign (using the API).
Some of the form fields are not rendered and are invisible in Docusign.
They show up completely fine on Chrome, pdfjs, Okular (Linux), Adobe PDF and Master PDF Editor.

This screencast shows the issue:

[image: showcase]

In docusign no field value is rendered.

I download the same PDF and open it in Okular (Linux, Poppler based PDF viewer) and the values are there.
I also open it up in Chrome and the values are there.

Please note that:

1. It happens to a specific PDF. We have a lot of PDF's that are working just fine.
2. The PDF is displayed properly using many different PDF software including pdfjs

Comment: are you getting 404 error in loading complete PDF or a part of PDF (may be some image in PDF)?

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign flattens / rasterizes incoming PDF documents to eliminate the security threats otherwise inherent in the PDF language.

PDF Form fields can be automatically converted to DocuSign fields (tabs). This can be done either while uploading a PDF using the DocuSign webtool or while uploading via the API.

If you have a specific PDF that doesn't render properly, you can contact DocuSign customer service for additional help.

If you want to maintain all of the PDF's features (not flatten it) you can use the DocuSign Signature Appliance to sign the PDF.